# Eagle: show package type in schematic

Tags: eaglecad

Is there some way to display package type of part in Eagle schematic. Something like name and value field but containing package information. It can be name of package associated with schematic symbol or empty field where something can be written manually.

How do I display package type in an Eagle Schematic?

Comment: Are you trying to display the package type that's already assigned to the schematic symbol, or just any editable package type?

Answer (score 2):

Options:

You can symply write the package information directly in the schematic.

You can add text to the symbol that just expands a special attribute, like PACKAGE.  The text string would be ">PACKAGE".  Nothing would shown in the schematic unless the PACKAGE attribute existed for that device.

In the device, you then set PACKAGE to whatever you want to show in the schematic for each variant.